# How to push/pull column for extra small devices using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout where it has two column "column-left" and "column-right". I can show them perfectly for all view port but I want when my view port is changed "column-right" will show at first then "column-left" (only for extra small devices e.g. Mobile). But currently it shows "column-left" at first then "column-right". I am using bootstrap 3. plz help.

Here is my html structure:

```
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
              <p class="text-center">Click here to see an up-to-date calendar for the Seaside Civic and Convention Center.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
             <p class="text-center">Not finding the room you are looking for, please visit our sister hotel</p>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to `float:right` the left column and `float:left` to right column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="hidden-xs">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <p class="text-center">Click here to see an up-to-date calendar for the Seaside Civic and Convention Center.</p>
        </div>
     </span>
     <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
         <p class="text-center">Not finding the room you are looking for, please visit our sister hotel</p>
     </div>
     <span class="visible-xs">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <p class="text-center">Click here to see an up-to-date calendar for the Seaside Civic and Convention Center.</p>
        </div>
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @luke is it possible to do this by col-push-*/col-pull-* ?

Comment: No, col-push/col-pull classes are intended for columns reordering but not for rows. It is possible to reorder rows with the help of relative position and media queries. For example you can use top: height_of_row for the first row and top: -height_of_row for the second row. Note that this will work only for rows with fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i misunderstand the question? But i think the accepted answer is wrong here. And also the comment about col-push/col-pull classes is wrong.

When you interchange your columns you can use the col-push/col-pull classes:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">
         <p class="text-center">Not finding the room you are looking for, please visit our sister hotel</p>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">
          <p class="text-center">Click here to see an up-to-date calendar for the Seaside Civic and Convention Center.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Notice that below the grid-float-breaking point the columns do not float at all (unless you use the xs grid by adding xs-col- classes). So the first column in your HTML will be shown first. When the columns start floating you can use the col-push/col-pull classes to interchange them.

The pull-right and pull-left classes in the answer of @rahul-kapuriya are not intend to manipulate the grid.

Alternatively you can apply a float:right; on your first column (also interchange your columns in the HTML first) with media queries. But why should you if you can use the  col-push/col-pull classes? Interchange your columns and add a `.content` class as follows:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-9 content">
         <p class="text-center">Not finding the room you are looking for, please visit our sister hotel</p>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
          <p class="text-center">Click here to see an up-to-date calendar for the Seaside Civic and Convention Center.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use the following Less code:

```
@media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint)
{
.content {
float:right;
}
}
```

The above Less code will compile into the following CSS code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really smart answer. Infact this should be the chosen answer. The chosen one is unnecessary extra code and somewhat just a workaround but not a solution. Unfortunately people are always looking easier, lesser intuitive, lesser smart answers but they actually lose the real power of knowledge it can empower them. Thanks for taking the time to enlighten me (though in a small way). Excellent stuff.